# How to set up an Amazon advertising API?

Tags: api, amazon-advertising-api

We have a client account of Amazon seller central. We need to pull campaign performance data from this account. With Amazon Advertising API we can pull this report.
Here are the documentation links:
[https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/AdProductsWebsite/downloads/Amazon_Advertising_API_Getting_Started_Guide.*TTH*.pdf](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/AdProductsWebsite/downloads/Amazon_Advertising_API_Getting_Started_Guide._TTH_.pdf)

[https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/AdProductsWebsite/downloads/Amazon_Advertising_API_Reference.*TTH*.pdf](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/AdProductsWebsite/downloads/Amazon_Advertising_API_Reference._TTH_.pdf)

I followed the procedure in Getting Started Guide

1) Created a developer account(Login with Amazon)

2) completed the sign up form as specified in second step.

I am not sure what to do next as I did not receive any reply from amazon regarding this. Does anyone faced similar issue before?
Thanks.

Comment: I keep getting a bad scope error... 

http://foo.com/?error_description=An+unknown+scope+was+requested&error=invalid_scope

Any suggestions?  I'm using the scope suggested by the documentation

scope=cpc_advertising:campaign_management

Comment: did you ever figure this out? @KlingonJoe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It takes two or three days from Amazon to reply in most case and as they are getting high volume of application it might be possible that they have rejected it so try more then once. And try to give some information to use in the comment section.

**In addition, a business registration in either NA or EU is required before they can grant permission to the Advertising API.**

After all this verification they can allow access.

Hope this help to you.

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 0):

If you have already received the onboarding e-mail, and you are sure that you are sending the correct API communications yet you are getting bad scope errors, then you are not yet White Listed so your requests are all rejected.

For me and many others I found while googling for hours to find the answer, this problem was due to not yet signing a license agreement which is in a very easy to overlook link hidden in a paragraph of the e-mail which starts: "Before you can register your application, you need to agree to the Amazon Advertising API License Agreement" Hit that link and accept the agreement to become white listed.

As a last resort if the above doesn't work, Amazon support had given me a direct e-mail to LWA and you can contact their support: lwa-support at amazon com.